# Functions of one complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I find all entire functions $f$ such that $f(x)=\exp(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb R$?

I thought I could find $f(z)$ by taking $z=x+iy$, which when intersects on the real axis 
becomes $z=x$, and $f(x)$ is given to be $e^x$.

So on the complex plane it would become $e^z$ as one of the wanted entire functions and it is more like an intuition but what I wanted to know is if $e^z$ is the right answer and the only answer and a method for finding $f(z)$.

Comment: Never use all caps. It is extremely rude.

Comment: Consider updating your question, so people on this site will be able to help you. Currently it's extremely hard to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Spaced What are all entire, complex functions $f$ such that $f(x)=\exp(x)$ for all real $x$? Obviously $f=\exp$ works, but perhaps there are other entire functions that work, and have $f(z)\ne\exp(z)$ for some complex $z\not\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry,but this is how it is asked in my text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is to find all the functions $f\in\mathcal O(\Bbb C)$ (which denotes the ring of entire functions, i.e. holomorphic on the whole complex plane) which coincide with the exponential on the real line $\Bbb R$, i.e. we are searching for  all the $f\in\mathcal O(\Bbb C)$ s.t. $f\equiv\exp$ on $\Bbb R$.

Now $\Bbb R$ is a subset of $\Bbb C$ which contains accumulation points, hence by the Identity Principle, such an $f$ must coincide to $\exp$ on the whole complex plane.

Hence $\exp$ is the only entire function which coincide with itself on the whole real line.

Comment: The question is to find entire functions that coincide with it on the _reals_.

Comment: Sorry, just edited.